# Get values from form in an iphone app to a php web appication in get method?

Tags: php, iphone, forms, zend-framework, get

i m trying to to get the request values of form in zend framework

earlier i was using the post method

but the the iphone app is sending me data in get method .

how do i can use it has i was using the post values like

$post = array(
            'id'=>'2',
          'email'=>'4',
            )

i want to get values also in this form value when a form is submitted .

i was using this to get post values

```
      $post = $this->getRequest ()->getPost ();
```

and i tried this to get get method values

```
    $post = $this->getRequest();
```

but

i get this error
        **Cannot use object of type Zend_Controller_Request_Http as array in**

this is the full error message

> "Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( [_paramSources:protected] =>
>   Array ( [0] => _GET [1] => _POST ) [_requestUri:protected] =>
>   /platinum-picks/p-picks/index/registration [_baseUrl:protected] =>
>   /platinum-picks/p-picks [_basePath:protected] => [_pathInfo:protected]
>   => /index/registration [_params:protected] => Array ( [controller] => index [action] => registration [module] => default )
>   [_rawBody:protected] => [_aliases:protected] => Array ( )
>   [_dispatched:protected] => 1 [_module:protected] => default
>   [_moduleKey:protected] => module [_controller:protected] => index
>   [_controllerKey:protected] => controller [_action:protected] =>
>   registration [_actionKey:protected] => action )  Fatal error: Cannot
>   use object of type Zend_Controller_Request_Http as array in D:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\platinum-picks\application\models\User.php
>   on line 267"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the values passed using GET method and you have done the same successfully with POST values. The only change you need to make in such a scenario is this:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost ();
```

becomes

```
$get = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

This will also return parameters from other sources:

> Retrieves a merged array of parameters, with precedence of userland params (see setParam()), $_GET, $_POST (i.e., values in the userland params will take precedence over all others).

So refer to the manual if this may be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `GET` variables using for example:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Or, for a specific variable:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('myVar');
```

This will also search for `POST` values. To search the `GET` vars only, use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getQuery('myVar');
```